# ControlValueAccessor not filling in remote service data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've had to recreate this question as the previous one went off tangent slightly and missed the key points of it.

I am trying to create custom component that I can bind to FormControl belonging to a FormGroup.

I've made it work if the user is entering data, the CVA works great, however if the data is being preloaded, i need it to auto select the object from the list which is retrieved from a remote service.

Unfortunately I always get undefined - undefined for the autocomplete option.

Here is the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7kscau-eko7d3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html.

Comment: from API you are getting empty array that's why you are getting undefined value in UI

Comment: ah, yeah. I'm looking at the code now, we should change up the structure a good bit here. You have multiple form controls in 2 different components. So what's this form supposed to do?

Comment: @Chellappanவ well yea that is the problem I am trying to solve, no matter the value I pass through it just doesn't trigger the observable that finds the relevant object in the array and saves it to the formcontrol.

Comment: what value are you trying to pass in to preload the auto-selected value? 'ferari'?

Comment: @DOZBORNE i am trying to split a large form into multiple smaller components for re-usability. In this case this part of the form has a autocomplete capability associated with it. If i removed the autocomplete and just had basic input field all is good, but the extra complexity is that autocomplete should retrieve the object from service and store it into the control.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I got that. Hold on, I'm trying to provide a solution now. One  min. Do you have discord? might wanna chat thru there to make it easier

Comment: @DOZBORNE no, but i know stackoverflow has chat room option, I just can't find the button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247614/discussion-between-dozborne-and-aeseir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was with your `onChange` function passing. I think I finally understood what you were trying to do.

```html
  <mat-autocomplete
    #auto="matAutocomplete"
    (optionSelected)="onSelected($event.option.value)" <--- HERE
    [displayWith]="displayWith"
  >
```

```ts
  onChange: (event) => void; // <-- this is just a state holder for the function that we get from the registerOnChange function. 

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn; // <-- assign this function to our local variable for use here
  }

  onSelected(event) {
    this.onChange(event); // <-- call this onChange function anytime the component is updated in order to tell the FORMGROUP something has changed.
// It doesn't know yet since the state is local
  }
```

Essentially, you have to call `this.onChange()` in order to inform the formGroup in the higher component something has changed. Because you didn't, it was never reflecting the object value back inside the top-level component.

However, since you are wanting to mutate the value immediately once passed from the formGroup inside the `writeValue()` method, you need to call `onChange()` there too. However, `onChange()` is actually not instantiated until *after* the `writeValue` function. So therefore, I've shown you how you can properly wait for it, rather than using something like an `asapScheduler`. I still don't think it's a good idea to do something asynchronously inside of the `writeValue`, I'm not sure exactly what your plans are here.

```ts
// implementation properly waiting for the onChange function to load

  private waitForRegister$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.waitForRegister$.pipe(filter(present => present),
      switchMap(() => this.carService.findCar(value).pipe(first()))).subscribe(val => {
      this.value = val;
      this.onChange(val);
    });
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
    this.waitForRegister$.next(true);
  }
```

Again, here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9xah4v?file=src/app/car-component/car-autocomplete.component.ts) for your visual aid.

Comment: sorry man, needed to get some sleep

Comment: @Aeseir did this solution work or no?

Comment: it meets the cut, i'll build on it